# how to display random image on a container in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

I am new at flutter. and I want to add random picture in a container how to add random picture from assets()?
For example when user use my application and refresh the page the picture in the container will change automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall make a list of all the asset files like this and so on...

```
List<String> assets=['assets/file1.png','assets/file2.png'];
```

in your build function call `assets.shuffle()`. This will reorder the assets file in random order and then make a variable imagepath as:-

```
String imagePath=assets[0];//now this will store a random image path ..
```

Whole code:-

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
List<String> assets=['assets/file1.png','assets/file2.png'];
String imagePath;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assets.shuffle();//shuffle over here
    imagePath=assets[0];//store random image over here
    return Container(
      child: Image.asset(imagePath),//show random image
    );
  }
}
```

You can also perform shuffle and other tasks in the initState of a statefull widget.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement something yourself. I would suggest adding possible images to a list

```
const List<String> randomImages = [
  "assets/images/image1",
  "assets/images/image2",
  "assets/images/image3",
  "assets/images/image4",
  "assets/images/image5",
];
```

Then using darts random class, Find a random int to use as an index that is bounded by the length of the string

```
Random random = Random()
int randomIndex = random.nextInt(randomImages.length)
Image randomImage = randomImages[randomIndex];
```